# A scenario to show better performance of having more RAM for SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server, performance, memory

I've asked for more ram for our SQL Server (currently we have a server with 4 GB of RAM) but our administrator told me that he would accept that only if I can show him the better performance with having more memory available because he has checked the server logs and SQL Server is using only 2.5 GB.

Can someone tell me how can I prove to him the effect of more available memory (like in a performance issue for a query)?

Comment: sql server 2008 64 bit,and window server 2008

Comment: Why have you asked for more ram for your SQL Server if it only uses 2½ of 4 GiB?

Comment: ...and how big are your databases (sp_spaceused not on disk)?

Comment: Is the 1.5 GiB not used by SQL Server free, or used by other processes?

Comment: because there lot's queries running on that server every day and I believe having more memory available should improve the performance .sql server would use as much memory as is available for it but in current server and setting this server doesn't have access to more memory !

Comment: @Simon :it's used by other processes

Comment: Is SQL Server configured to use 2.5 GB as max amount of memory (Server - properties?.

Comment: yes 2.5 is the max allowed memory because we have other processes that need rest of memory and I know that the reason of log !

Comment: Well... that kind of explains why the server logs says that SQL Server only use 2.5 GB. If it was allowed to use more memory it probably would.

Comment: Tell your DBA what you told us, that it's only using 2.5 GiB because that's the _configured maximum memory limit_. You need more to be able to rise that limit without disturbing other processes.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the fact that you don't appear to have memory issues...

Some basic checks to run:

1. Check the Page Life Expectancy counter: this is how long a page will stay in memory
2. [Target Server Memory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/teekamg/archive/2007/11/06/sql-server-memory-related-performance-counters.aspx) is how much RAM SQL Server want to use

Note on PLE:

"300 seconds" is quoted but our busy server has a PLE of 80k+. Which is a week. When our databases are 15 x RAM. With peaks of 3k new rows per second and lot of read aggregations.

Edit, Oct 2011

I found this article on PLE by Jonathan Kehayias: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/post/Finding-what-queries-in-the-plan-cache-use-a-specific-index.aspx

The comments have many of the usual SQL Server suspect commenting